# 301 redirect .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Задача стоит сделать редирект с одного домена, на другой. За исключением каталога /old/

Сам редирект сделать легко, а вот как сделать исключение для каталога при редиректе понять не могу.

**UPD**

Маленькое уточнение.
Со старого сайта надо перенаправлять на новый сайт в не зависимости от адреса.

Поясню. 
Есть два адреса:
example.com/?p1
example.com/?p2

Надо чтобы со всех страниц перенаправляло на newexample.com

За исключением папки old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере переадресация всех станиц старого сайта на главную страницу http://new.site.com/ кроме папки somefolder, все страницы в папке somefolder доступны по прежнему адресу.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somefolder 

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://new.site.com/ [L,R]
```